# Scaling the x-axis in ListLogLogPlot[] or ListLogPlot[] in lieu of DataRange

Tags: plotting

I will present my existing workaround but I am wondering if there is a better solution that takes less time (my solution seems to ~double the time it takes to produce the desired plot).  Using DataRange would be ideal, but I'm either missing something or it doesn't work when a ListPlot has logarithmic axes.

I have some data in a list (1D) that I'm plotting with ListLogLogPlot.  I know that the x-values should range from 1 to 5000; with ListPlot I would just use DataRange to take care of this.  However, DataRange seems to do nothing when using ListLogPlot or ListLogLogPlot.

Let's do an example:

```
    fakedata = Table[1/x, {x, 1, 100, .1}];
    ListLogLogPlot[fakedata, Frame -> True, ImageSize->500]
```

[image]

Adding DataRange->{1,5000} does nothing to the plot.  I can instead make a new list, composed of the x-values since I know they should vary linearly from 1 to 5000 over the length of the data:

```
    sol = Solve[1 == m + b && 5000 == m*Length@fakedata + b, {m, b}];
    fakexvals = 
       Table[Evaluate[x*m + b] /. First@sol, {x, 1, Length@fakedata}];
```

Using this new list, I can get the desired plot:

```
    ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{fakexvals, fakedata}], Frame -> True, 
    ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

This is *ok* for this example, but it becomes cumbersome with the data set is large.  It appears to take Mathematica roughly twice as long to create the list plot from x-y pairs versus just y-values.  I have some data sets with 200,000 points and for these generating a list plot from {x,y} pairs takes between 10-20 seconds.

Comment: DataRange only works if you give a list of single values to these functions.  It does not work if you give a list of value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Rescale` to map the range {1,100} to {1,5000} :

```
rescaledX = Rescale[#, {1, 100}, {1, 5000}] & /@ Table[x, {x, 1, 100, .1}];

ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{rescaledX, fakedata}], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah that's a nifty little function that I wasn't familiar with.  The issue still remains, though, that it would be a plot of {x,y} pairs which makes it take much longer.

Answer (score 3):

In v8.0 on Windows 7, `DataRange` seems to do what it's supposed to:

```
data = Table[1/x, {x, 1, 100, .1}];
ListLogLogPlot[data,
 Frame -> True,
 ImageSize -> 500,
 DataRange -> {1, 5000},
 PlotRange -> {{1, 5000}, {0.01, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow you're right.  I happen to still have v8 installed so I loaded it up and checked.  It looks like in v9 it no longer works.  That's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, this seems to be a MM9 bug (as it was working in MM8 correctly). As a quick workaround I put together a FixDataRange function:

```
FixDataRange[dr_][data_] := Module[{res, xd , nop},
   If[Length[data[[1]]] == 0,
    nop = Length[data];
    xd = Rescale[Range[nop], {1, nop}, dr];
    res = Transpose[{xd, data}];
    ,
     res = Map[FixDataRange[dr], data, {1}];
    ];

   res
   ];

(* Test FixDataRange *)
data = Table[Abs[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[Abs[Sin[2*x]], {x, 0, 10, 0.1}];

ListLogPlot[data, DataRange -> {0, 10}]
ListLogPlot[FixDataRange[{0, 10}][data]]
ListLogPlot[FixDataRange[{0, 10}][{data, data2}]]
```